# Pyomo - adding/removing decision variables

Tags: pyomo

Colleagues and I are building an optimization model using Pyomo and are trying to reuse the sample concrete model to solve several instances. There are two types of changes in the instances: (1) change in the constraints; and (2) change in the number of decision variables (to coincide with the constraints).

While I have found deactivate/activate for constraints, I have not been able to find how to change the number of decision variables within a model between calls to a solver. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent for variables to the activate/deactivate for constraints is the fix/unfix method.

For instance, `model.X.fix(0)` to fix the variable to a value of 0 (essentially rendering it a non-decision variable). To unfix it, simply write `model.X.unfix()`.